# NoClassDefFoundError for clojure-hbase

Tags: clojure

How to add the necessary jar file for the classpath used by the project?
The `project.clj` is copied below:

```
  1 (defproject hbase01 "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  2   :description "FIXME: write description"
  3   :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  4   :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
  5             :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  6   :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]
  7                  [clojure-hbase "0.92.4"]])
```

At the REPL I tried:

```
user=> (require '[clojure-hbase.core :as hb])
```

and it answered back:

```
CompilerException java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:  
    org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration, compiling:(clojure_hbase/core.clj:1:1)
```

I found one jar file `/usr/local/hbase/lib/hadoop-common-2.2.0.jar` where the class is an inner class... but how to add this path to the project?

I have read and tried the [lein-localrepo](https://github.com/kumarshantanu/lein-localrepo) but it did not get installed in the right location, the jar file get installed into the `$username/.m2/repository/hadoop-common` folder.

Comment: try `(require ['clojure-hbase.core :as 'hb])`

Comment: thanks for reading ! The two statements are the same, so the same error message.

Comment: Can you post what's in your ~/.lein/profiles.clj?

Comment: The profiles.clj file is copied below:  {:user {:plugins [
                    [lein-difftest "2.0.0"]
                    [lein-try "0.4.3"]
                           [lein-localrepo "0.5.3"]
                  ]}}

Answer (score 1):

You may have already figured this out, but in case anyone else comes looking for this error. You need to include a jar from the Hadoop project with the [Configuration](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration.html) class, as HBase has a dependency on it from what I've found.

I had this error with Clojure 1.6.0 and HBase 94.26.

My project.clj includes:

`[org.apache.hbase/hbase "0.94.26"]
 [org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-core "1.2.1"]`

Just run `lein deps` and you're off to the races.

Comment: hi Matt and thanks for the hint. By adding the two lines in my project.clj file seems OK and I can run [ lein deps ].

Comment: hi Matt and thanks for the hint. By adding the two lines in my project.clj file seems OK and I can run [ lein deps ]. Are you able to use the API exposed by the [clojure-hbase] (https://github.com/davidsantiago/clojure-hbase ) ?                                                                                   It never returns :                                                                                   15/03/25 22:35:11 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x14c53c42c120008, negotiated timeout = 40000

Comment: Sorry Dag, I've been using the Apache HBase Java client API directly. I haven't used any of the wrapper libraries in Clojure.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to note here is that you have conflicting versions of clojure. You specify 1.6.0 and clojure-hbase [still requires 1.5.1](https://github.com/davidsantiago/clojure-hbase/blob/master/project.clj#L3). This could probably cause the issue you're seeing.

Comment: I have updated the project.clj file for using 1.5.1 and re-tested , it answered back with the same message ..... Does it work for you ? thank you!